# MYSQL - Get Records that has a NULL for a Column, AND records that has more than 1 COUNT of that same Column

Tags: php, mysql

Gouging my brain out as I was not able to produce my desired output

I initially have this query

```
SELECT * FROM SilverShop_Order WHERE Code = "HBOPD" AND Status != "Unpaid"
```

But then,

1. I only want to display the records that has a NULL value for the `MainReference` column AND an additional condition that
2. if a record has more than 1 value of the same `MainReference`, I also want to include them

I have this improved query

```
SELECT * FROM SilverShop_Order WHERE Code = "HBOPD" AND Status != "Unpaid" AND Reference IN
(
    SELECT Reference FROM SilverShop_Order WHERE MainReference IS NULL 
)
```

Which was able to satisfy my 1st desired condition but my 2nd condition is that, I want to display the other records that has the same `MainReference`

[image: Sample 1]

With the picture above, naturally, `695891` will be included in the fetched data, but will not include `695891.01` because the condition must have more than 1 same `MainReference`

[image: Sample 2]

And with the example above, I'll include the `649490`, `649490.01` AND `649490.02` since the `MainReference` was able to detect more than 1 same `MainReference`

Can anyone kindly help me out what should be my query please?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would try with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM SilverShop_Order t1
LEFT JOIN Silvershop_Order t2 ON (t1.MainReference = t2.MainReference AND t1.ID != t2.ID)
WHERE t1.Code = "HBOPD" AND t1.Status != "Unpaid" AND
(t1.MainReference IS NULL OR t2.MainReference IS NOT NULL)
```

What's making this possible is that you're joining table SilverShop_Order with itself, via MainReference, but join clause also contains condition that ID of those joined records should be different. Which is kind of count, only without a count - if you got anything but NULL on t2.MainReference, it means that you have at least 2 records with same MainReference.

Comment: this is the closest query, but still producing duplicates that are unwanted, still playing around with your query

Answer (score 0):

> And with the example above, I'll include the 649490, 649490.01 AND 649490.02 since the MainReference was able to detect more than 1 same MainReference

Test this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table t1
JOIN ( SELECT COALESCE(MainReference, Reference) ref
       FROM table t2
       GROUP BY ref
       HAVING COUNT(MainReference) > 1 ) t3 ON COALESCE(t1.MainReference, t1.Reference) = t3.ref
/*
UNION
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE MainReference IS NULL
*/
```

Comment: hello sir @Akina, how can I combine your answer to my `SELECT * FROM SilverShop_Order WHERE Code = "HBOPD" AND Status != "Unpaid" AND Reference IN
(
    SELECT Reference FROM SilverShop_Order WHERE MainReference IS NULL 
)` ?